# How to efficiently use the result of a Hasura query for another query?

Tags: postgresql, graphql, subquery, hasura

I am currently querying my Hasura database using userId to get location.

```
users(where: {id: {_eq: 1528}}) {
    location
}
```

I then use location to query users near that one user.

```
    users(
      where:
        { location: {_st_d_within: {distance: 20000, from: $point }}},
    ) {
      firstName
      city
      region
    }
  }
```

Is there a way to efficiently combine these two queries such that I only query once?

Comment: Hi I'm a little confused how using multiple filters in the same query helps. I first need to query using the id 1528 to get the location. Only then do I have the location to filter the next series of results.

Comment: hmmm ... you can't do that in one query

Answer (score 3):

You can not combine these two queries into one.

What you can do is create a Postgres function and query that function instead as described in Hasura's documentation:

https://hasura.io/docs/1.0/graphql/manual/schema/custom-functions.html#example-postgis-functions