# Is it better to use asyncStorage or to query hasura database for persistent latitude / longitude data in react native / expo app?

Tags: postgresql, react-native, expo, asyncstorage, hasura

I am currently querying my Hasura database using userId to get location. This is for my video-based React Native / Expo application.

```
users(where: {id: {_eq: 1528}}) {
    location
}
```

I then use location to query users near that one user.

```
    users(
      where:
        { location: {_st_d_within: {distance: 20000, from: $point }}},
    ) {
      firstName
      city
      region
    }
  }
```

It turns out I cannot combine these two queries into one query, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62181428/how-to-efficiently-use-the-result-of-a-hasura-query-for-another-query).

**My question is: is it more efficient to query twice like above or to store location as asyncStorage within my Expo / React Native application?**

If I store location within asyncStorage, I could use the following function to retrieve latitude, for example.

```
export const _retrieveLatitude = async () => {
    try {
      const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@latitude');
      if (value !== null) {
        return parseInt(value); 
      } else {
          return 0; 
      }
    } catch (error) {
        return 0; 
    }
};
```

What is better practice?

Keep in mind, the only data being stored in latitude / longitude. This can be considered persistent data, because all I need from the user is her general location, rather than her specific location.